# to read the packet of bytes on client(client Socket) from server(ServerSocket) using java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, packet

i m a new .
i m a java developer(fresher) and currently i m working on BSE project and i m facing problem to read the packet of bytes on the client(client socket) from the server(server socket). if u can help me then please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem are you facing, and what do you need help with ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to interact directly with packets, then you need to use a [`DatagramSocket`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) instead of the regular `Socket` and `ServerSocket`.

Then, you should [visit this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.net/DatagramSocket.htm) to see a good tutorial on how to get started with sending and receiving individual packets.

The basic idea is that the Client or Server will block on the `recieve()` call while it waits for its partner to send a packet using `send()`.

If you aren't interested in the individual packets like you indicated in your question, then you will want to use `Socket` and `ServerSocket`.  The first step to communicating between the two involves code that will look similar to the following:

```
//Server
// this call will block until the client tries to connect to the server
Socket cientConn = new ServerSocket(8878).accept();
// now you can use the connection's input and output streams to send data

/******************/

// Client
Socket serverConn = new Socket(addressOfServer, 8878);
// now you can use the connections input and output streams
```

After you get connections set up, you will have basically 2 read/write loops.  One on the client, and one on the server.

```
while(true) [
    // check for data from an input stream
    ...
    // respond with message back
}
```

You will need a similar loop for the client and the server.

Comment: thanks, i have created whole server socket and i have written packet on server socket successfully and i have created client socket also but i m not be able to read packet so please give me the idea about read the packet(code or example) on client socket and tell clearly that can i read a packet on client socket or not if no then what should use in place of client socket and server socket.

Comment: i m creating connection oriented server(TCP).

Comment: thanks, i m creating connection oriented server/client(TCP) socket.i have created whole server socket and i have written packet on server socket successfully and i have created client socket also but i m not be able to read packet so please give me the idea about read the packet(code or example) on client socket and tell clearly that can i read a packet on client socket or not if no then what should use in place of client socket and server socket.

Comment: @deepak, Your question is too vague.  I have updated my answer with a little more information, but could you please update your question with some more information?